# Angular2-meteor cant read property "meteorInstall"

Tags: angular-meteor, angular2-meteor

I'm converting an old angular2 project over to use meteor to act as an admin panel style thing for a project that is based off the ionic2-meteor whatsapp tutorial.

So I'm building the website in the client folder inside api.

I'm pretty sure I've got things correct (based off the old socially tutorial) for the angular2 client.

I'm getting these as errors though.

```
modules.js:13538 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
es5-shim.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at es5-shim.js:17
    at es5-shim.js:2789
promise.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at promise.js:17
    at promise.js:582
ecmascript-runtime.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at ecmascript-runtime.js:17
    at ecmascript-runtime.js:4630
babel-runtime.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at babel-runtime.js:17
    at babel-runtime.js:160
random.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at random.js:18
    at random.js:368
```

I imagine that I have probably missed an import or something somewhere but can't work out where.

Any help would be awesome.

These are the packages I have installed.

```
meteor-base@1.0.4            
mobile-experience@1.0.4       
mongo@1.1.15                   
reactive-var@1.0.11            
jquery@1.11.10                 
tracker@1.1.2
standard-minifier-css@1.3.3
standard-minifier-js@1.2.2
es5-shim@4.6.15
ecmascript@0.6.3
shell-server@0.2.2
angular2-compilers
barbatus:typescript
accounts-base@1.2.14
npm-bcrypt@0.9.2
accounts-password@1.3.4
reywood:publish-composite
http@1.2.11
alanning:roles
check@1.2.4
dispatch:mocha-phantomjs
tmeasday:publish-counts
hwillson:stub-collections
practicalmeteor:mocha
xolvio:cleaner
```

~Edit

///the error comes from @angular/http module, I'm going to try rolling it back to see if it helps.

```
/**
 * \@experimental
 *
 */
export var QueryEncoder = (function () {//<---- this is the line causing the error
    function QueryEncoder() {
    }

    QueryEncoder.prototype.encodeKey = function (k) { return standardEncoding(k); };

    QueryEncoder.prototype.encodeValue = function (v) { return standardEncoding(v); };
    return QueryEncoder;
}());
```

rolling back and forward didn't help at all.

Comment: The meteorInstall error is coming because the modules.js isn't compiling and its required by everything else.

I looked into the line thats causing the error in the modules file and I can't see whats causing the error
I've posted it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. For me it was due to recently installed ionic plugin. It has started working normal after removing that plugin. Please try removing your recently added plugin. I hope you have tried that by now.

Comment: yes, we ended up rebuilding the project and found that a few things were causing it to happen, so we decided against using those plugins and used others instead.